# How many agents we can make in dialogflow,when I constatntly deleteing the agents after making

Tags: dialogflow-es

How many agents we can make in dialogflow,when I constantly deleting the agents after making.So now when I am making the new agent now,Its cancelled all the time.

The error found:
com.google.apps.framework.request.NotFoundException: No DesignTimeAgent found for project 'corona-info-bpua'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All Dialogflow projects are also Google Cloud projects, so you are subject to the same [project quota limits](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/limits) that your account has under Google Cloud. Initially that is 5 projects, but you can see exactly how many you have and request additional projects.

Deleting a project does not immediately free it up for a new project, but rather it is [soft deleted](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#console_4) and held in that state for 30 days before it is completely deleted. While in a "soft deleted" state, it continues to count against your quota.

Visit the [Google Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/) to see all your projects, deleted or not, and request additional project quotas.